# Титул страницы по умолчанию - "My Yii Application"

Tags: yii, yii2

Откуда берется в самом титуле страницы эта надпись - "My Yii Application"?

```
<title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имя приложения по дефолту где-то в ядре прописано.

Чтобы свое задать надо в конфиге задать имя

```
return [
  ....
'name'=>'Your New Application Name!',
....other...info
```

и тогда во `view` можно писать `$this->title = Yii::$app->name;`, где тайтл будет браться из конфига

Также по дефолту это может быть прописано в индексных файлах, например у `basic` приложения вo  `views/site/index.php`, а у `advanced` версии в `backend/views/site/index.php`и `frontend/views/site/index.php` соответственно.

Comment: Не-не. Но все равно спасибо. Это имя страницы (title). Берется например из : views/site/index.php  --- $this->title = 'My Yii Application'; ---

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Да, посмотрел, видимо с некоторой версии 2.0.6 они начали так делать. На всякий случай обновил ответ для будущих пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

Название берется тут: `\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php` в строке 99: `$name = 'My Yii Application'`

Comment: Вообще-то плохо менять файлы сторонних библиотек/фреймвёрков.

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласен, но Вы внимательней прочитайте поставленный вопрос, а потом оценивайте коментарии, цитирую: "Откуда берется в самом титуле страницы эта надпись - "My Yii Application"?"